# Probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with given marginals and given correlation matrix

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, st.statistics, probability-distributions, time-series

In all what follows, let $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ denote the set of probability measures on $(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n))$ and $\mathcal{C}_n$ the set of $n \times n$ correlation matrices.

**First Question**

For $n$ a positive integer and $\lambda \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^1)$, consider the set
$$
\mathcal{P}_{n, \lambda} := \{\mu \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^n): \mu \circ \pi_i^{-1} = \lambda, \forall i\}
$$
where $\pi_i : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is the canonical projection,
i.e. $\pi_i(x_1, \dots, x_n) = x_i$.

Now, for $\lambda$ such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\lambda(dx)|x|^2 < \infty$, consider the map
$c_n: \mathcal{P}_{n, \lambda} \rightarrow \mathcal{C}_n $ that assigns to each probability measure in $\mathcal{P}_{n, \lambda}$ its correlation matrix.

I would be interested in knowing when $c$ is surjective, i.e.

- For a given $n$, what are the probability measures $\lambda$ such that $c_n$ is surjective?
- For a given $\lambda$, what are the integers $n$ such that $c_n$ is surjective?
- (Most importanlty), what are the probability measures $\lambda$ such that $c_n$ is surjective for all $n$'s?

**Second Question**

Now let's assume that there is a $\lambda$ such that $c_n$ is surjective for all $n$'s
(actually $\lambda = \mathcal{N}_{0,1}$ is indeed such an example, and what I am really asking here is if there are non Gaussian probabilities that satisfy such a condition). If $\gamma: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a stationary autocovariance function, I can definitely construct for all $n$-uples of integers
$(t_1, \dots, t_n)$ a probability measure $\mu_{t_1, \dots, t_n} \in \mathcal{P}_{n,\lambda}$ having as a correlation the matrix whose element $(i,j)$ is $\gamma(t_i-t_j) / \gamma(0)$.

I obviously agree that, without injectivity of $c_n$, I would have many ways to construct $\mu_{t_1, \dots, t_n}$, but let's say that I chose one.

At this point, I would like to know if the $\mu_{t_1, \dots, t_n}$, where the collection is indexed by all the finite tuples of integers, are necessarily consistent in the sense of Kolmogorov's extention theorem so that I can construct a weakly stationary process $(X_t)_{t \in \mathbb{Z}}$ having $\gamma$ as autocovariance function and $\lambda$ as the distribution of $X_t$, for all $t$'s.

**Motivation**

I guess it's clear where I am coming from.

I know that for every stationary covariance function $\gamma: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, there is a weakly stationary process $(X_t)_{t \in \mathbb{z}}$ such that
$$
cov(X_t, X_s) = \gamma(t-s).
$$
But the only proof of this fact that I know is constructing a *Gaussian* measure on $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{Z}$ so that it will yield a *Gaussian* process (which is actually not only weakly but also strictly stationary) such that $X_t \sim \mathcal{N}_{0,\gamma(0)}$ for all $t$'s.

So what I wanted to know is: given a $\gamma$, can we construct *other* weakly stationary processes, with a prescribed distribution of $X_t$?

Comment: You packed a lot of questions into one problem. You are more likely to get answers if you ask questions one at a time.